# Sql Server User vs Role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security

In Sql Server 2005, what is the difference between a database user account that is mapped to an active directory group vs. a database role that is contains the same active directory group as a member?

Answer (score 6):

In SQLServer, Server logins are mapped to AD users / groups at the server level.

Logins are then mapped to DB users.

Adding db users to roles allows you to set permissions against all the users in the role with a single statement.

For example, if you added all the users that work in customer services to a new role called CustServ, you could write one grant execute script that grants the role (and hence all it's members) execute permission.

Answer (score 1):

A role is a privelege group, whereas a User is a person or Active Directory group. For example, an AD group "IT_Developers" may have Writer access to a database, but the AD group "Domain Administrators" aren't neccessarily admins on the database.  There are also different kind of admins, which Active Directory doesn't know about.

Comment: So, if I have an AD group "MyDomain\IT_Developers", a database user "DBU" mapped to MyDomain\IT_Developers and a database role "DBR" that contains MyDomain\IT_Developers as it's only member  I can assign object permissions to either entity.  Is there any functional difference between the two?